# Getting Claims With IdentityServer3

Tags: oauth-2.0, asp.net-web-api2, identityserver3

I'm following the [Using OAuth to Secure Your ASP.NET API](https://app.pluralsight.com/library/courses/oauth-secure-asp-dot-net-api/table-of-contents) course on [Pluralsight](http://%20http://www.pluralsight.com). I've set up IdentityServer with a number of InMemoryUsers, one of which looks like this...

```
public static List<InMemoryUser> Get()
{
    return new List<InMemoryUser>
       {
           new InMemoryUser
           {
               Username = "user@domain.com",
               Password = "password",
               Subject = "user@domain.com",
               Claims = new[]
                        {
                            new Claim(Constants.ClaimTypes.Id, "96cddc1de66641829237b7f09869b1c8"),
                            new Claim(Constants.ClaimTypes.Name, "Some Full name example
                        }
           },
       };
}
```

If I authorise the user and use the supplied access token to call the API, the claims collection, for that user, looks like this ...

```
((User as System.Security.Claims.ClaimsPrincipal).Identities.First() as System.Security.Claims.ClaimsIdentity).Claims.ToList()
Count = 10
    [0]: {iss: https://localhost:44375}
    [1]: {aud: https://localhost:44375/resources}
    [2]: {exp: 1468920204}
    [3]: {nbf: 1468916604}
    [4]: {client_id: my_clientid}
    [5]: {scope: openid}
    [6]: {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/nameidentifier: user@domain.com}
    [7]: {http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/authenticationinstant: 1468916604}
    [8]: {http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/identityprovider: idsrv}
    [9]: {http://schemas.microsoft.com/claims/authnmethodsreferences: password}
```

If I drop the access key that I'm using in to the debugger at [jwt.io](http://jwt.io) I get this...

```
{
  "iss": "https://localhost:44375",
  "aud": "https://localhost:44375/resources",
  "exp": 1468921471,
  "nbf": 1468917871,
  "client_id": "my_clientid,
  "scope": "openid",
  "sub": "user@domain.com",
  "auth_time": 1468917871,
  "idp": "idsrv",
  "amr": [
    "password"
  ]
}
```

I'm unclear what it is I'm doing, or not doing, that is stopping the Claims that are defined from being returned.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are hitting the default behaviour of Microsoft's JWT token handler.

Microsoft thinks it knows what claim types are best for you so they do you a favour and change them on the fly (so they think).

you can either accept that - or turn that behaviour off by calling this beautiful piece of code somewhere (e.g. in startup):

`JwtSecurityTokenHandler.InboundClaimTypeMap.Clear()`

Comment: I've added that to the very top of the Configuration method of the Startup class in the IdentityServer Project but to no avail. Stepping through my code I note that the Claims I'm expecting are all in the collection when I'm handling the `AuthenticateLocalAsync` method in my user service (since posting the original question, I have moved away from InMemoryUsers)

Comment: Added it to the top of the Configuration method of the Startup class in my **API** project and it worked!

Comment: In the current version of AspNet Core this has changed to             JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultInboundClaimTypeMap.Clear();